# Get first word after string

Tags: c

I am using esp8266, i need to take first work isnide quotes after the word "+CWLAP:"

Here is my output result.

```
AT+CWLAP
+CWLAP:(3,"MainNetwork",-76,"00:15:6d:a6:61:fa",1,107,0,5,3,3,0)
+CWLAP:(1,"SubNetwork",-79,"00:4f:62:19:19:43",9,85,0,0,0,3,0)
```

OK

I need to print MainNetwork and subNetwork.
Here is what i am trying to do

```
char *p =strtok(Receive.bytes, "+CWLAP:"); 

p = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
p = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
printf("%s\r\n",p);
__delay_ms(20);

p = strtok(NULL,  "+CWLAP:");
p = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
p = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
printf("%s\r\n",p);
__delay_ms(20);
```

For some reson i am taking this in my output

```
MainNetwork
,1,107,0,5,3,3,0)
+CWLAP:(1,
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should not call strtok on a RX buffer, since it changes the contents. Either parse through the data manually or copy it before calling strtok.

Comment: I can pass the data into another buffer and then to call strtok, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
char *p =strtok(Receive.bytes, "+CWLAP:");
p = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
```

by

```
char *p =strstr(Receive.bytes, "+CWLAP:"); 
p = strtok(p,  "\"");
```

because in your first strtok "+CWLAP:" is a string of separators, so *strtok* will give you *AT* placed before the '+'

is similar for the second but *strtok* add null characters so the second *strstr* must be done before any *strtok*.

A full solution can be :

```
  char * p1 = strstr(Receive.bytes, "+CWLAP:"); 
  char * p3 = strstr(p1 + 7, "+CWLAP:"); 
  char * p2;

  p2 = strtok(p1,  "\"");
  p2 = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
  printf("%s\r\n",p2);

  p2 = strtok(p3,  "\"");
  p2 = strtok(NULL,  "\"");
  printf("%s\r\n",p2);
```

Additional remark, *strtok* modify Receive.bytes adding null characters, may be you need first to duplicate the string (*strdup*) ?

Execution :

```
MainNetwork
SubNetwork
```

---

And to manage any number of lines :

```
char * p1 = strstr(Receive.bytes, "+CWLAP:");

while (p1 != NULL) {
  p1 += 7; /* bypass +CWLAP: */

  char * p2 = strstr(p1, "+CWLAP:");
  char * s = strtok(strchr(p1, '"') + 1,  "\"");

  printf("%s\r\n", s);

  p1 = p2;
}
```

I replaced the first *strtok* by a *strchr* because we don't need the intermediate string

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer with some explanation? Why does OPs code not work? Why does yours?

Comment: Maybe elaborate the meaning of the delimiter "string", which seems to be OPs core misunderstanding.

Comment: Your example should be replaced in both of my strings? Or only to second one?

Comment: @user10775950 I edited my answer to put a full solution

Comment: Thank you it works, but what if i need to get more networks?

Comment: @user10775950 in that case you need a loop and some changes for that yes, but the philosophy is the same

Comment: @user10775950 search and if you really do not find ask me

Comment: Much better now. For the benefit of beginners I however still miss the explanation that the delimiter string in strtok looks for any single of the given characters, while strstr looks for the whole string (i.e. this is  more detailed than "is a string of separators", which is basically correcr, but not so easily digestable...).

Comment: @user10775950 like I did with p3 you have to save hte pointer to the next CWLAP before to do the strtok

Comment: @Yunnosch it is not forbidden for the people to do `man strtok` or to search on internet for more details about the function ^^

Comment: Did you read the strtok man? I did, and when reading it from beginners point of view, I think that it is as insufficiently digestable. Do not get me wrong, your answer is good for experienced people, but I think SO should aim at beginners as well. The (advanced) beginners are those who give the upvotes you know....

Comment: @Yunnosch yes I read that man ^^. If needed search on stackOverflow or internet (google) to find examples more easy to understand than the man :-)

Comment: @user10775950 I modified my answer to manage any number of networks

Answer (score 0):

Since `strtok` modifies the source array, `strcspn` can be used to iterate through the array along with `strstr`.
The search can be wrapped in a loop to find all the matches.
`strstr` will find an exact match of the sub-array in the source array.
From the match, `strcspn` will count the characters to next character in the source that matches any character in the delimiter string. Here only a quote is used as a delimiter. If `strcspn` does not find a match it counts to the terminating zero.
This prints the matching string but `strncpy` could be use to copy the string. Pay attention to the terminating zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char bytes[] = "AT+CWLAP\n+CWLAP:(3,\"MainNetwork\",-76,\"00:15:6d:a6:61:fa\",1,107,0,5,3,3,0)\n+CWLAP:(1,\"SubNetwork\",-79,\"00:4f:62:19:19:43\",9,85,0,0,0,3,0)";
    char *quote = "\"";
    char *cwlap = "+CWLAP:";
    char *match = NULL;
    char *openquote = NULL;
    char *closequote = NULL;
    size_t skip = 0;
    size_t span = 0;

    closequote = bytes;
    while ( closequote && *closequote) {//not NULL and not zero terminator
        if ( ( match = strstr ( closequote, cwlap))) {//find exact sub-string match
            skip = strcspn ( match, quote);//count characters to quote
            openquote = match + skip;//point to quote
            if ( *openquote) {//not at terminating zero
                openquote++;//point to character after quote
                span = strcspn ( openquote, quote);//count characters to quote
                closequote = openquote + span;//point to quote
                if ( *closequote) {//not at terminating zero
                    printf ( "%.*s\n", (int)span, openquote);//print span number of characters
                    closequote++;//point to character after quote
                }
            }
            else {
                closequote = NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            closequote = NULL;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```